# Yeoman Generator - How to Parse Package.json of Generator Project

Tags: javascript, json, yeoman

I have the following, standard folder structure within my generator.  The task I am current struggling with is I currently have a templated _package.json that I write to disk for the main generation.  There is one variable in the written package.json I would like to hydrate which is the actual version of the generator project.  Basically, I want to be able to determine via the new generated api project's package.json which version of the generator was used to construct the project, so that I can target older versions and mark them for updates.

I have tried to accomplish this in both various generator steps like prompting.js and writing.js and via the following code:

```js
var fs = require('fs');

let pkgGeneratorAPIVersion = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('../../package.json', 'utf8'));
```

but it isn't working.  I keep getting the following error:

```js
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'package.json'
    at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:646:18)
    at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:551:33)
    at module.exports.prompt.answers
```

I've tried various relative paths to no avail.  Is there a better way to parse the json file?  Is my relative path off?  Any help is greatly appreciated.

[image: Folder structure]

Answer (score 1):

I ended up fixing it with the following:

```js
var pkgJSON = require('../../package.json');
this.answers.corePkgGeneratorAPI = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(pkgJSON)).version;
```